# Quick Change and Edit Stock QTY simple product

Tags: configurable-product, products-management, simple-product, stock-status, qty-increment

is there any methods to change easily and directly all simple products of a configure product? without having to open and edit one by one inventory on simple product. But edit directly on manage product QTY column.... is it possible? [image: edit directly]pic attached.

Comment: There not have any easy process to update Qty of all simple products of a configure product.

Comment: only you can do this by csv upload

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update same no of qty for multiple product than you can do it by selecting products and select update attributes action in actions drop down of product grid.

After submitting action you find inventory tab there you can change qty for selected products.

[image: Please find attached image]